# How do I resolve a "maas": no public ssh keys found. error?

Tags: juju, maas

I am encountering an error when installing Juju:

```
juju bootstrap
ERROR error parsing environment "maas": no public ssh keys found.
```

I have installed RSA key which is found in my root folder after I have used my root user to create it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

By default, juju looks in the current user's `~/.ssh` for a public key file; it'll choose (in order of preference) `id_dsa.pub`, `id_rsa.pub`, or `identity.pub`, and will authorize that key for the `ubuntu` user on every machine it provisions.

If your setup is more complex, you can edit your environment configuration to specify the path to an `authorized_keys` file containing any number of public keys (or, indeed, a single public key in another location):

```
environments:
  maas:
    ...
    authorized-keys-path: /path/to/authorized-key(s)
    ...
```

...but, if you don't have a corresponding private key in an expected location, you may need to edit `~/.ssh/config` to specify an `IdentityFile` before you can use `juju ssh`, `juju scp`, `juju debug-log` or `juju debug-hooks`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it failed because the file did not exists. Creating the file solved the issue.

```
mkdir $HOME/.ssh
touch $HOME/.ssh/authorize_keys
```

Comment: The authorized_keys file is copied to the ubuntu user on the nodes, such that it must contains the required public keys if you want to SSH on the nodes. Self-login would be `cp .ssh/id_rsa.pub .ssh/authorized_keys`.